# How to choose the proper array in java to store XML data

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am new to Java and trying to create a cataloging program as a beginning exercise. I've made the interface and I can populate the initial `JComboBox` with the titles the way I want but my issue comes with storing the rest of the data so that it can be easily retrieved based in the title from the `JComboBox`.

My xml looks something like this:

```
<Movies>
<Movie>
    <Title></Title>
        <Studio></Studio>
    <Director></Director>
    <Actors></Actors>
    <Rating></Rating>
    <Stars></Stars>
    <Review></Review>
    <Synopsis></Synopsis>
    <Genre></Genre>
</Movie>
</Movies>
```

with multiple movie elements. I want to store the data for each movie in some form of array so that I can populate the rest of the form fields with the proper data when a user selects a title from the JComboBox. But I can't decide on a good array type to do this. It seems to me I need some kind of array that looks like this:

```
Array<"Title1" -> "Title", "Studio", ....;
      "Title2" -> "Title", "Studio", ...;
       and so on...>
```

I've been looking into different arrays like `Hashmaps`, `ArrayLists`, `Multi-Dimensional String Arrays` and maps but none of these seem to do what I'm thinking.

I'd really appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create a class `Movie` with fields for Title, Directory, Actors, etc? You can then have a list containing all your movies.

If the movies are uniquely identifiable by their name, you can put them in a HashMap with the name of the movie as the key and the `Movie` object as the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think HashMap or HashTable will be enough for your specification.

You can use String for key ( Title1,Title2 etc..)
You can use ArrayList for values(Title , Studio etc...)

```
String key = "Title1";

List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
value.add("Title");
value.add("Studio");

Map<String, Arraylist> myMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();
myMap.put(key,value);
```

Comment: I would like to say that this works perfectly as well. If I could pick two answers I would.